# Computing IntStream pattern

Tags: java

> Question 1: Stream (10 points)
> By constructing a single stream pipeline, complete the following pattern method to generate the output as shown in the sample jshell session.
> Assume that the answer is saved in the file pattern.jsh, and begin your answer with:
>
> ```
> String pattern(int n) {
>     return ...
> }
> jshell> import java.util.stream.*;
> jshell> /open pattern.jsh
> jshell> System.out.println(pattern(3));
> 321.21..1
> jshell> System.out.println(pattern(5));
> 54321.4321..321...21....1
> jshell> /exit
> ```

How do I attempt this question and print out the dots in order?

This is the code I have written:

```
IntStream.iterate(5, x -> x > 0, x -> x -1 )
    .flatMap(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0,x).map(y -> x - y))
    .mapToObj(x -> x == 0 ? "." : x + "")
    .reduce("", (x, y) -> x + y);

And this is the result i got:

    "54321.4321.321.21.1."

I just dont know how to increment the dot part. Will be grateful if someone can help me out on this. Thank you
```

Comment: so you need to complete the method `String pattern(int n) {
    return ...
}`? forget streams for a while, first try out a normal iterative approach and then you would find things easier to transform.

Comment: yea but i assume n is 5 to test out my answer. The main aim is to get the following result in a single pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 IntStream.iterate(5, x -> x > 0, x -> x -1 ).boxed()
.flatMap(x -> IntStream.iterate(5 , y -> y > 0 , y -> y - 1)
.mapToObj(y -> y > x ? "." : y + ""))
.reduce("", (x,y) -> x + y);
```

With the help of @Joni, I managed to make my code work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: for each number x in range 5 to 1 generate a sequence of y 5 to 1. If y > x, emit ".", otherwise emit y.

```
String pattern = IntStream.iterate(5, x -> x > 0, x -> x - 1)
    .boxed()
    .flatMap(x -> IntStream.iterate(5, y -> y > 0, y -> y - 1)
        .mapToObj(y -> y > x ? "." : y + ""))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you also want an algorithmic solution. We can observe that sting length is n*n and we want dots if modulo is bigger than division result, otherwise we want modulo+1.

```
Stream.iterate(n*n-1,x->x-1).limit(n*n)
                .map(x -> x%n>x/n ? ".":String.valueOf(1+x%n))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Sample for 6:

> 654321.54321..4321...321....21.....1